# Pug iteration give me duplicate data

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

so i used pug loops to show 2 docs of my collection but when it's going to show them, it shows them twice.
here is the code:

```
            each request in requests
              -if(request.course.master.id===user.id)
                each reqUser in request.course.users 
                  tr
                    td=request.course.name
                    td=reqUser.name
                    td=reqUser.email
```

this is a request doc of my requests collection  ===>

```
_id:61c879ab1fd17239e85a8b7a
duration:Array
price:Array
createdAt:2021-12-26T14:16:55.302+00:00
expiresAt:
2022-01-25T14:16:55.302+00:00
accepted:true
course:ObjectId("61b60458acbb1fa4598eea36")
user:ObjectId("61c879941fd17239e85a8b68")
id:"63341"
```

**i have access to the course of this request and i want the user of this course.**

also this is the course doc of my courses collection ===>

```
_id:ObjectId("61b3708276844971620c98ea")
images:Array
users:Array
name:"assembly "
imageCover:"course-assembly"
duration:Array
master:ObjectId("61c2bfc0ac2f110af04903a2")
```

in the pug code up there , first i want to check if the current logged in user is the master of the given course or not;
then if it's true i want to make a row for each user of the course but
it gives 2 completely same rows for each user
in this shape ===>

1. courseName , user1Name , user1Email
2. courseName , user2Name , user2Email
3. courseName , user1Name , user1Email
4. courseName , user2Name , user2Email

Comment: #1 what is duplicated? rows, cols? #2 print the size of requests, request.course.users !

Comment: It's impossible to help without knowing how your data is structured.

Comment: yes thanks for telling, now i've completed that question

Comment: You question is not formatted well, first the `request.course` does not contain `name` property `course:ObjectId("61b60458acbb1fa4598eea36")` cause the object is mongodb's `ObjectId`